# what is the meaning of stable in zfile_stable - CZMQ

Tags: c, zeromq

`CZMQ` man page for `zfile` explains `zfile_stable` as:

> //  Check if file is 'stable'
>
> CZMQ_EXPORT bool zfile_stable (const char *filename);

What is the meaning of stable? when a file is said to be stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use case here is using files to signal between processes. The example application is FileMQ, which publishes new files out to subscribers. But there's no obvious way to know when a file has been "created"; the two solutions I know are to create a second "signal" file, which is rather clumsy, or to use this "has the file been modified in the last second" algorithm.

Let's say you're copying photos into one directory, and a parallel process is detecting new photos and uploading them to a server. On a large photo, the modified date will keep changing until it's stable. Then, it's safe to upload the photo.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of stable in this context is if a file more than 1s old.

See https://github.com/zeromq/czmq/blob/master/src/zfile.c#L115

Comment: what is the usage of it? I mean what is the philosophy behind it?